# Logistic regression and Biostatistics and spss!

Tags: regression, logistic, biostatistics

I have problem with my data.I dont know the exact method in order to analyse them.I have made 10 experiments into 9 different cell groups.The 10th is the control group.I have put copper in three different concentrations at 3 out of 10 cell groups and then i put 6 different concentrations of copper and EDTA(helps cells against copper).I would like to see...if there is a connection between copper concentration and death and then i would like to see wheather EDTA helps cells to live more. Should i use logistic regression?But how should i put my data on spss?

Comment: How is death measured in each experiment?

Comment: i put 0 for death and 1 for live...And i have all the sums for death cells and for live cells in every group.

Answer (score 1):

You can use logistic regression for this. There may be other better models (e.g., mixed models).

The most straightforward setup in SPSS is:

- Each row in the data file should be a separate observation.
- The first variable should contain 0 or 1, where a 1 indicates a death.
- The second variable should contain the copper level.
- The third variable should contain the EDTA level.

Then, you fit a logistic regression, playing around with whether or not to treat the predictors as categorical and whether or not to interact them.